# How to handle a 400 error with Ember Data (2.4.0-canary)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't figure out if my problem has to do with my query or my response or something else.

In my route I'm using a `queryRecord`:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.queryRecord('invitation', { 
    'invitation_token' : params.invitationToken 
  });
},
```

I'm properly receiving on the server side but I'm testing the case where the invitation token no longer exists. Therefore, the server is returning a 400 with a json payload which has an explanation of the error.

```
{"error":"Error finding invitation"}
```

But back on the ember side I'm just getting two errors (really it is just one).

```
Error while processing route: accept-invitation Ember Data Request GET /api/users/invitation returned a 400
Error: Ember Data Request GET /api/users/invitation returned a 400
```

It used to be (under Ember 2.2.1):

```
Error while processing route: accept-invitation Adapter operation failed Error: Adapter operation failed
Error: Adapter operation failed
```

What am I supposed to be returning from the server in the case that the token wasn't found? These messages makes it looks like something unexpected happen within Ember.

I'd assume that a 400 would tell Ember that there was an error, and it would go to the error state for the route. But instead it goes to the error state at the application level and spits out these error messages in the log.

I'm *expecting* the server to return a 400, so I'm not sure why Ember is complaining. What should I be returning and how should I properly handle this?

Comment: have you tried something like this ` handleResponse: function(status, headers, payload){
    if(status === 400 && payload.error){
      return new DS.InvalidError(payload.error);
    }
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }`

Comment: Thanks @Bek - if I try that (and adjust the params for InvalidError) I get: Error while processing route: accept-invitation The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid Error: The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your application should be returning a response that is formatted differently. As per [the JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors),

> Error objects MUST be returned as an array keyed by errors in the top
>   level of a JSON API document.

The specification also specifies that the following members, among others, may be provided (see the link for the full list).

> **title**: a short, human-readable summary of the problem that SHOULD NOT
>   change from occurrence to occurrence of the problem, except for
>   purposes of localization.
>
> **detail**: a human-readable explanation
>   specific to this occurrence of the problem. Like title, this field's
>   value can be localized
>
> **status**: the HTTP status code applicable to this problem, expressed as
>   a string value.

If you try returning something along the lines of what is below, how does the tooling behave?

```
{
  "errors": [
   {
    "status": "400",
    "title": "Error finding invitation"
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I am using the Active Record Adapter/Serializer.