# Errors not populated

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework, json-api

I receive errors from the backend:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "extra_comments": [
      "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "name": [
      "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "due_date": [
      "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "price": [
      "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "payment_type": [
      "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "description": [
      "This field may not be null."
    ]
  }
}
```

I try to show them in my template:

```
{{#each model.errors.messages as |message|}}
  <div class="error">
    {{message}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Nothing is shown. A problem with EmberData? A problem with changes in Ember template syntax? A problem with Ember? The adapter? My backend? No idea. The problem surface is too big. How can I:

- display the received ajax reply?
- make sure that EmberData is processing the reply and populating `model.errors`?
- Show the processed `model.errors` in the console?

In general, I am experiencing that new versions of Ember are very hard to debug. Whenever I show any Ember object in the console, I just see some `Computed` properties which are not computed whenever I try to peek into them.

### EDIT

My backend is:

- Django 1.9
- with [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
- [django-rest-framework-json-api](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api)

I am not sure if `django-rest-framework-json-api` is able to return JSON Api conform errors. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues/188).

Comment: Did you see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570160/how-to-handle-a-400-error-with-ember-data-2-4-0-canary)?

Comment: @Keo: thanks. Yes that's a similar problem (with a different backend)

Comment: Just curious, where do those errors come from? I'm using `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` and that's missing the `errors` field in the response.

Answer (score 2):

The errors you receive from your backend aren't [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) conform [errors](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors).
You have to transform the errors in a custom serializer's `extractErrors` method (see the [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractErrors) documentation for an example) or you change the backend to return JSON API conform errors.

An example of [multiple errors](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects-multiple-errors) conform to the `JSON API` spec:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": "403",
      "source": { "pointer": "/data/attributes/secret-powers" },
      "detail": "Editing secret powers is not authorized on Sundays."
    },
    {
      "status": "422",
      "source": { "pointer": "/data/attributes/volume" },
      "detail": "Volume does not, in fact, go to 11."
    },
    {
      "status": "500",
      "source": { "pointer": "/data/attributes/reputation" },
      "title": "The backend responded with an error",
      "detail": "Reputation service not responding after three requests."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right, but I do not know why. My backend is returning JSONApi data when requests are successful. No idea why it doesn't when there are errors. I have opened an issue: https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues/188. I'll wait for a reply to accept an answer here.

Comment: I have added an example to your answer.

Comment: And BTW, I would say EmberData documentation is wrong: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html

Answer (score 0):

Going through the code [I found](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/blob/develop/example/settings/dev.py#L43) that this setting is needed on the django side:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_json_api.exceptions.exception_handler',
    ...
}
```